# mssql_fetch_array is not showing all results - where is a problem

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I will join the topic - I have a sql query:

```
SELECT a.tw_Nazwa, c.st_Stan, d.zd_Glowne , d.zd_Zdjecie, a.tw_Id, a.tw_Symbol,e.cht_IdCecha,b.tc_CenaNetto1,b.tc_CenaBrutto1
FROM tw__Towar  a
LEFT JOIN tw_CechaTw  e ON a.tw_Id = e.cht_IdTowar
LEFT JOIN tw_Cena  b ON a.tw_Id = b.tc_IdTowar
LEFT JOIN tw_Stan c ON b.tc_IdTowar=c.st_TowId
LEFT JOIN tw_ZdjecieTw  d ON d.zd_IdTowar=c.st_TowId
WHERE tw_SklepInternet = 1 AND st_MagId = 1
```

This query is supposed to have 261 results and that's what it takes if it's done to the database by the Dbeaver program.

Using:

```
$getResults = sqlsrv_query($conn1, $Query);
if( $getResults === false ) {
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );

}
```

and

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
//blablabla
$i++;
}

print $i //is showing only 12 results
```

This is working but is not solution:

```
    for($i=0;$i<=260;$i++){
    $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)
    //blablabla
    $i++;
    }
```

Error while fetching array.

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => IMSSP
                [SQLSTATE] => IMSSP
                [1] => -22
                [code] => -22
                [2] => There are no more rows in the active result set.  Since this result set is not scrollable, no more data may be retrieved.
                [message] => There are no more rows in the active result set.  Since this result set is not scrollable, no more data may be retrieved.
            )

    )
```

where is the mistake and how to get around it.

Comment: it looks like there are empty lines - how to avoid it to continue using the while loop

Comment: use `$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $getResults );` and use `$row_count` in `for()` instead of hard-coded `260`

Comment: @spamfilter If `while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($getResults, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {$i++;}` returns `12` rows and you expect `261`, check if you execute your two statements in the same database.

Comment: with $params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ); is working good - this is solution for me ok thx

Answer (score 0):

```
$params = array();
$options =  array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET );

$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $stmt );
```

is working - THX ;)